# QGIS web client installation: this.projectSettings.capability is undefined

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

I am trying to debug my configuration of [QGIS web client](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Web-Client).

I have the same problem illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506570/quantumgis-mapserver-and-web-client-can-not-display-standard-helloworld-map-res) (the GIS-Browser appears but it keeps `loading map` for the two sample projects ). Yet following the instructions in the same post doesn't solve the problem for me.

The apache log doesn't indicate any error, just warnings

```
Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Warning 1: Unable to find driver JP2ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Warning 1: Unable to find driver JP2ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
```

Yet debugging the page where the maps don't load I get the JS error

```
TypeError: this.projectSettings.capability is undefined
```

I can't find any explanation of that.

Comment: Which Operating System do you use?

Comment: @Thomas Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 1):

As long as your QGIS Server won't send a proper response your webclient won't work. So perhaps you could check first what you get as response when you try to get the GetCapabilities-Response.

Just adapt the following link to your local settings and paths:

http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&map=/opt/geodata/test123.qgs

Do you get a correct response back?

Comment: almost 5 years later, same question, different poster, different OS (W10).
Getmap says layer (countries) does not exist, getcapabilities says it does exist and is queryable and has EPSG:4326.
The only weirdness, I assume without consequences, is:
<Exception>
<Format>XML</Format>
</Exception>
Comments quite welcome!

Comment: The ECW and JP2ECW warnings imo can be neglected w.r.t. getting a first web-output. They mean that there is no gdal support for these formats, as can be verified by running gdalinfo --formats [ | sort]. As raster formats, not relevant for outputting geography. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137169/qgis-web-client-installation-this-projectsettings-capability-is-undefined may help.
In my case I'm left with the contradiction that getmap says a layer does not exist, while getcapabilities says it does exist. After solving a number of other issues, getting fed up.